# Drawing chart visualization with Google Fusion tables

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to dynamically draw a chart based off a click on a fusion table layer/map. Whenever a state in Mexico is clicked, I would like the chart to change to reflect the value in columns 2007, 2008, 2009, and 2010. At the moment, this is not working. Firebug is telling me that 'a is undefined' but I don't really know what that means, as I have not declared a variable named 'a' and am assuming it's something in the Google script.

This is the code that I'm using. The click listener grabs the state name from the column named 'column_1' and then passes that to the draw visualization function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(shownLayer, 'click',function(e){
    stateName = e.row['column_1'].value;
    drawVisualization(stateName);           
});  


function drawVisualization(stateName){
    google.visualization.drawChart({
        containerID: "textBox",
        dataSourceUrl: "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",

        query: "SELECT '2007','2008','2009','2010' " +
          "FROM 3943497 WHERE column_1 = '" + stateName + "'",
        chartType: "ColumnChart",
        options: {
            title: stateName,
            height: 300,
            width: 400
        }
    }); 

}
```

The map website is located here: https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/csterling/web/cartel%20map/index.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with google.visualization, but I'd start by at least getting a static chart displaying, then worry about changing the chart on click.

Comment: I have done this, and understand how to do it. I think the problem is in getting the data from the fusion table.

Answer (score 0):

```
containerID: "textBox",
```

is mispelled. Should be:

```
containerId: "textBox",
```

My suggestion was to get a basic static GVis chart working first before worrying about linking it to Fusion Tables and changing the chart based on a mouse click.  I took the relevant parts of your script but could not get it to work. When you post your whole file it's very hard to separate the issues giving you problems from the rest of your code.  This is what I extracted to test the basic GViz issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['corechart'] });
    window.onload = function () {
       drawVisualization('Chiapas');
    }
   function drawVisualization(stateName){
       google.visualization.drawChart({
           "chartType": "ColumnChart",
           "containerId": "textBox",
           "dataSourceUrl": "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
           "query": "SELECT '2007','2008','2009','2010' " + "FROM 3943497 WHERE column_1 = '" + stateName + "'",
           "options": {
               title: stateName
           }
       });
   }

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="textBox" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
     <br />
   </body>
   </html>
```

This application does not work.  I'm getting displayed in the page:
"Bars series with value domain axis is not supported"

I can also see in your app that the stateName value you are using is "Chiapas, Mexico" but that is not the value shown in your Fusion Table column_1, "Chiapas" is a value there.

Comment: Thanks! But fixing that still doesnt generate the chart.

Comment: I think there's a problem with you using two forms of the Maps API javascript. You can remove one and use: google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:"sensor=false"});

Comment: I know that you can use both Maps and Charts in the same javascript. Check out this example by google: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/adv_fusiontables